# Investment Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

You make an investment.  Assume that returns are normally distributed with a mean return of .15 and a standard deviation of .1.

A) Suppose you check on your return once a year.  What is the probability that your return is positive?

B) What is your return if you check it once a month?

C) Let us define the ratio of noise to performance as the coefficient of variation (the ratio of standard deviation to the mean). In situations A and B, calculated number of parts of noise per part performance.

I'm trying to find the equation for A&B but not finding any luck.  Also the language for C is really confusing.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Is that supposed to be _annual_ return distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = .15, \sigma = .1)?$ And do you know if those are decimal fractions or percentage returns? (These days 15% would be fantastic, 0.15% is about what my bank wants to give me on a savings account.) This Question might get a lot cheerier reception here is you showed your attempted answer to one of the parts. (This is not a good place to 'outsource' your homework.) Anyhow, CV is easy: $\sigma/\mu = .1/.15,$ _regardless_ of scale.

Comment: If you *show* what you *have* tried, people will be more willing to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site.  Yes, M = .15 and standard dev = .1.  I don't understand what it means by check once a year.  Does that mean (1/365).  Does once a month mean (1/31).  Sorry, I'm not trying to outsource my homework I'm just confused where to begin because I haven't seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

I will *assume* $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = .15, \sigma = .1)$ is the annual return. And I assume checking once a year means you would see the random
return $X.$ You are asked for $P(X > 0).$

I don't know whether you are supposed to use printed normal tables or software
to solve this. To use printed normal tables, you need to *standardize.*
The 'standard score' $Z$ corresponding to the 'raw score' $X$ is found as
$X = (X - \mu)/\sigma.$ (Read about this in your text or lecture notes; the
terminology may be different, but the idea has to be the same.)

So you can solve part (A) as follows:

$$P(X > 0) = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{0 - .15}{.1} = -1.5\right)
= P(Z > -1.5).$$

You will have to read in your text how to get the answer, using the particular kind of normal
tables in your text or the kind of software used in your course. Below is a
sketch of the standard normal density function. The total area under the
density curve is 1. The curve is symmetrical about 0. Half of the area is on either side of 0. The area you seek is to the right of the vertical red line.
(Just by looking you can see that the answer has to be a probability more than 1/2. This makes
sense because you've been promised an annual gain of $X,$ which has a positive
mean.)

[image]

My guess is that your gain in *one month* would be $Y = X/12.$ So $\mu_Y = 0.15/12$
and $\sigma_Y = 0.1/12.$  By working through what I have shown you above,
I hope you are now sufficiently 'un-confused' to do part (B).

Comment: Yes you have, thank you for the help.